# SQL Search Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've got a single table in a SQL database I want to search. I have ensured that full text search is turned on. I set up a catalog and an index. I am using the following code with the errors below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchByKeyword]
    @Keyword AS VARCHAR(255) = 'Analyst'

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @InternalKeyword VARCHAR(300)

SET @InternalKeyword = '"' + @Keyword + '"'

SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[sbir_export].[sbirID], [dbo].[sbir_export].[TopicName]
From [dbo].[sbir_export]
WHERE 
    CONTAINS([Description], @InternalKeyword);
END
```

> Error     SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near
>   ''C:\Users...\SearchByKeyword.sql''. Miscellaneous
>   Files SQLQuery1.sql   3
>
> Error     SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script: CREATE
>   FULLTEXT CATALOG [sbirFullTextCatalog]
>       AUTHORIZATION [dbo];  sbirDec2016 C:\Users...\bin\Debug\sbirDec2016.sql
>
> Error     SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 9982, Level 16,
>   State 100, Line 1 Cannot use full-text search in user
>   instance. sbirDec2016 C:\Users\C...\bin\Debug\sbirDec2016.sql

Comment: What happens when you try a simple select?  No stored procedure and no variables.

Comment: What version of SQL are you on (SELECT @@VERSION;)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need Full Text Index:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[sbir_export].[sbirID], [dbo].[sbir_export].[TopicName]
From [dbo].[sbir_export]
WHERE [Description] LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'
```

Comment: but i got it to work. Problem was with my index...doh.